# Store mySwiper.activeIndex after page refresh

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

On my carousel I have a mySwiper.activeIndex call on the touchEnd event. I was wondering if it's possible to store that value in a variable so after a page refresh I could call a mySwiper.slideTo(index, speed, runCallbacks) method and slide to the last index called.

Sorry if this doesn't make sense, basically I would like to click on a slide (that's a link to a project page) and when I click back to the main page, the slider is in the same position (index).

Any help would be awesome :) thanks!

Comment: `localStorage`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a prime candidate for LocalStorage you can save key value pairs to be persisted in the browser.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

in your case when your touchEnd event ends you'd store the index like so.

```
window.localStorage.setItem('slider-index', index)
```

and when retrieving

```
window.localStorage.getItem('slider-index');
```